# Trying to run a jest test failing on an import, might be related to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I'm working on a node set of APIs that I'll be testing with Jest. When I'm running the application by itself is working fine, but when I run the tests is failing with this error

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

  at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
  at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
  at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
  at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
  at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:51:28)
/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at new ReadableState (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:111:25)
    at BufferList.Readable (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:183:25)
    at BufferList.Duplex (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
    at new BufferList (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
    at new MessageStream (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
    at new Connection (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:51:28)
    at /Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:35:29
    at callback (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
    at TLSSocket.connectHandler (/Users/--/dev/FullStack/React/part4/blog-list/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:309:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:427:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1504:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:918:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:688:12)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I've read some other posts that using `jest.useFakeTimers()` should work to solve this, but this is not the case for me

This is my test file

```js
const app = require('../app')
//const supertest = require('supertest')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const listHelper = require('../utils/list_helper')
//const api = supertest(app)

const blogs = [
  {
    _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
    title: 'React patterns',
    author: 'Michael Chan',
    url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/',
    likes: 7,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
    title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url: 'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html',
    likes: 5,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
    title: 'Canonical string reduction',
    author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
    url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html',
    likes: 12,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
    title: 'First class tests',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll',
    likes: 10,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
    title: 'TDD harms architecture',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html',
    likes: 0,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
    title: 'Type wars',
    author: 'Robert C. Martin',
    url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html',
    likes: 2,
    __v: 0
  }
]

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers()
})

test('get all blogs', () => {
  // await api
  //   .get('/api/blog')
  //   .expect(200)
  //   .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
})

test('dummy returns one', () => {
  const result = listHelper.dummy(blogs)
  expect(result).toBe(1)
})

describe('total likes', () => {
  test('when list has only one blog equals the likes of that', async () => {
    const result = listHelper.totalLikes(blogs)
    expect(result).toBe(36)
  })
})

describe('return favorite blog', () => {
  test('when blog has most likes', async () => {
    const result = listHelper.favoriteBlog(blogs)
    expect(result).toEqual(
      {
        title: 'Canonical string reduction',
        author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
        likes: 12
      })
  })
})

afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

Jest config file

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  timers: 'fake',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js']
}
```

And the package.json

```js
{
  "name": "blog-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose --runInBand"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable for this line.  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex; Try to look for this error.

Answer (score 3):

`mongoose.connection.close()` returns a Promise that isn't being awaited anywhere. I'm betting that the Promise is closing the connection after Jest has already torn down the environment.

If you make the callback in `afterAll()` an async function and await the call to `mongoose.connection.close()`, I think that will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks that really helped after that change. Also, for some reason I had to initialize the db I was using ( a test db) by adding some elements, but it works with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! You also need to close express in this way if you import your express server after the .listen() command.